# Name convention for Reader and Writer

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to name a component that will be capable of both reading from an `InputStream` (file or otherwise), and writing to an `OutputStream`; thus serving both as a `Reader` and as `Writer`.

So far the best I've come up with is:

- `ReaderWriter`
- `IOStreamManager`
- `StreamManager`

Any good ideas?

Comment: This needs more context to be sure, but it sounds as if you're focusing on the wrong level here. I would expect such a component to be called `RatingsManager` or `FuelMonitor`, not `ReaderWriter` just because it reads and/or writes stuff.

Comment: If you mean the tool is meant to connect an inputstream to an output stream I would use IoChannel. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/channel

Comment: I pondered this recently, and I concluded that if I need to read and write a resource at the same time, I will just create two streams (a Reader and a Writer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest StreamIO. I don't like the word "Manager" for class or component names, it is too much of a loaded word.

Comment: I like your suggestion - I ended up going with `IOStreamer`.

Comment: What about FileProcessor since deals with a reader, a writer, streams and so on.